# Error messages from NDSOlve

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a boundary value problem with `NDSolve`. The code is:

```
sol = Block[{M = 0.0}, 
  NDSolve[{
    f'''[x] + f[x]*f''[x] - f'[x]*f'[x] - M*f'[x] == 0, 
    f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 1, f'[15] == 0}, 
    f, x, 
    MaxSteps -> 10^5, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 50, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 50, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50, 
    Method -> 
     {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 1, f''[0] == -0.5}}]]
```

The `f''[0] == -0.5` that you see in the `Method` option is just trial and error on my part. When I execute the code, I get the following error messages.

> NDSolve::precw: The precision of the differential equation ({0.
>   (f^[Prime])[x]-(f^[Prime])[x]^2+f[x]
>   (f^[Prime][Prime])[x]+(f^(3))[x]==0,f[0]==0,(f^[Prime])[0]==1,(f^[Prime])[10]==0})
>   is less than WorkingPrecision (50.`). >>
>
> NDSolve`Reinitialize::precw: The precision of the argument function
>   ({f[0]==0,(f^\[Prime])[0]==1,(f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0]==-0.5}) is less
>   than WorkingPrecision (50.`). >>
>
> NDSolve::ndtol: Tolerances requested by the AccuracyGoal and
>   PrecisionGoal options could not be achieved at x == 0. >>
>
> NDSolve::ndtol: Tolerances requested by the AccuracyGoal and
>   PrecisionGoal options could not be achieved at x == 0. >>
>
> NDSolve::ndtol: Tolerances requested by the AccuracyGoal and
>   PrecisionGoal options could not be achieved at x == 0. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of NDSolve::ndtol will be suppressed
>   during this calculation. >>
>
> NDSolve::berr: There are significant errors
>   {4.3180842775472223126931759314001997855580001822181*10^-78,-0.50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,0.50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}
>   in the boundary value residuals.  Returning the best solution found.>>

I am completely stuck on the prolem. Please help me with this.

Comment: You're mixing precision quite badly here, which leads to these error messages. How much precision do you really need in the result? Just remove `MaxSteps -> 10^5, AccuracyGoal -> 50, PrecisionGoal -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 50` and you'll get an answer straight away without any problems. If you really need high precision, note that `WorkingPrecision` has to be higher than `AccuracyGoal`/`PrecisionGoal`, and you should avoid introducing values (such as `0.0` and `-0.5`) with less than your working precision.

Answer (score 1):

```
sol = Block[{M = 0.0}, 
 NDSolve[{
f'''[x] + f[x]*f''[x] - f'[x]*f'[x] - M*f'[x] == 0, 
f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 1, f'[15] == 0}, 
f, x, 
MaxSteps -> 10^5, 
 AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, 
PrecisionGoal -> 50,  WorkingPrecision->MachinePrecision ,
Method -> 
 {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 1, f''[0] == -0.5}}]]
```